# PHP_SELF with htmlspecialchars Strange behaviour

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I read all the posts regarding PHP_SELF and htmlspecialchars and I did according to it. But I am not sure whether the behaviour of my website is correct or not.

Below is my code.

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post" id="enquiryform" name="enquiryform">
```

When I type url as http://mydomain.com/enquiry.php?alert('hacked'), it works fine.

But when I type

```
    http://mydomain.com/enquiry.php/<script>alert('hacked')</script> 
      or 
    http://mydomain.com/enquiry.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E
```

It displays page without any css. But it does not show any alert box in any case (even if I dont use htmlSpecialchars).

I am confused what is happening here.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: you're check `enquiry.php` vs the `index.php` ?

Comment: "When I type url" where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation is correct. If you don't use `htmlspecialchars`, you're susceptible to this potential scenario:

```
http://mydomain.com/enquiry.php/"><script>alert('hacked')</script>
```

All you're missing in your scenario is the `">` to break out of the current tag.

What htmlspecialchars does is escape the potentially-malicious string so that it cannot be interpreted as raw HTML.